# Flickering in GDI regardless of using memory DC and BitBlit

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I tried to avoid flickering in GDI by creating a memory DC, loading a empty created bitmap in it, doing all the drawing to memory DC, and at the end BitBlitting to pDC. 
But yet, the flickering still happens? Why? 
Is it possible that is related to using EMF-s, or something like that? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to eliminate all other drawing directly to the screen.  The usual culprit is `WM_ERASEBKGND`.  Handle it and do nothing (because you'll put whatever background you want into the offscreen DC)

Comment: Thank you Sir, I've done that, but still, nothing changed. Can you possibly think of any other reason that can provoke that?

Comment: Aha, it works! I made a mistake while changing the handler. Thank you very much! Can you explain to me why this happens, if I'm blitting everything on the screen at once? Is it perhaps that this handler is called before the OnDraw method? It clears the area first, and then calls it, is that correct? Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: @breakpoint: Exactly.  `DefWindowProc` handles `WM_ERASEBKGND` by drawing over the entire window using the background brush.  That's pretty much guaranteed to cause flicker.  It's not that one handler is called before the other while handling `WM_PAINT` -- they handle separate messages sent by Windows.  But Windows sends `WM_ERASEBKGND` before `WM_PAINT`, in many cases.